# Generating a PDF on the client side

Tags: pdf-generation, single-page-application

I would like to generate a PDF with a QR code for a web-app I'm making. Should I generate the PDF on the server side or the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, generating on the server has the following advantages:

1. more options - tools/libraries, language support, fonts etc
2. storage options - your servers can store the PDF if required in a db/document-store
3. security - your storage options are all secured on the server and hidden from the browser
4. reliability - your PDF will be generated on the server, stored and available to the client.  This same PDF can live for as long as required in storage and delivered to the client whenever required.  You can confirm any time that the PDF the client has is the same one as stored.

Generating on the client might be quicker, so it depends on what the life-cycle of your PDF is as to which path is best.

I hope that helps.